# Making non-graphical Histogram from array values

Tags: java, arrays, histogram

Via the starPrint method  I need to make the frequency of each number populated in the array display in a histogram as such:

```
1=3***
2=4****
3=7*******
```

and so on. It needs the number of stars populated that are equal to the frequency of the number appearing! At the moment I'm getting the number of asterisks of the length of the array.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int matrix[][] = new int[100][2];

    for (int row = 0; row < matrix.length; row++) {
        for (int column = 0; column < matrix[row].length; column++) {
            matrix[row][column] = (int) (Math.random() * 6 + 1);
        }

    }
    int[] hist1 = frequency(matrix);

    String star = starPrint(hist1);
    for (int i = 1; i < hist1.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(" \n" + hist1[i] + star);
    }

}

public static String starPrint(int[] value) {

    String star = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {

        star += "*";
    }
    return star;
}

public static int[] frequency(int[][] matrix) {

    int[] nums = new int[7];

    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
            nums[matrix[i][j]] += 1;
        }
    }
    return nums;
}
```

Comment: What's the question? :-)

Comment: I need to make the frequency of each number populated in the array display in a histogram as such: 1 = 1 time *  

and so on.  Edit : The formatting won't let seem to let me do it here but it needs the number of stars populated that are equal to the frequency of the number appearing!  Edited in main question for clarity.

Comment: Reformatted code; please revert if incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing, stars should be changing right ? then

```
String star = starPrint(hist1);
```

should be within here

```
for (int i = 1; i < hist1.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(" \n" + hist1[i] + star);
}
```

Second your `starPrint` method will have to change (unless that is how method is stated in the homework ???) from

```
public static String starPrint(int[] value) {
```

to

```
public static String starPrint(int value) {
```

which means that you will need the value that you got at random and not the length of the array

```
for (int i = 0; i < value; i++) {
```

Not value.length

Comment: This looks very close to working but I tried this but it's trying to apply an array to an int value, which isn't working.

Comment: Well this is not working code to copy and paste. Since this was tagged as homework I gave very close to the answer suggestions. You need to change `String star = starPrint(hist1);` to `String star = starPrint(hist1[i]);` to use the new `starPrint` method

Comment: Thanks so much.  Finally.  I've been working on this thing all day and my brain is fried.  I don't know if this will ever really click for me.  I'm beginning to lose hope!  3rd programming class. I should be better than this by now, right?

Comment: It takes time , scrap paper and water.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an [example](http://home.roadrunner.com/~jbmatthews/war.html) in [Ada](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ada_%28programming_language%29) that may guide you.

```
Max_Count  : constant Integer := 1_200;
Bin_Size   : constant Integer := 100;
--
type Histogram is array (0 .. Max_Count / Bin_Size - 1) of Integer;
Graph : Histogram := (others => 0);
--
for J in Graph'Range loop --'
   TIO.Put(Label(J));
   for K in 1 .. (Graph(J) * Plot_Size) / Game_Count loop
      TIO.Put("*");
   end loop;
   TIO.New_Line;
end loop;
```

Addendum: Note that `starPrint()` always returns the same number of stars. Each time you print the value of `hist1[i]`, print out that many stars.

Addendum: Consider changing `starPrint(int[] value)` to `starPrint(int value)`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a `Map<Integer, Integer>`?  You could iterate through the array, and for each number check to see if it was currently a key for the map.  If so, get the associated value and increment it.  If not, put the number in the map, along with the number of times it has occurred so far (one).

Then when it come to printing the histogram, just iterate through the `keySet()` of the map, and get the values.

Comment: It's homework so I have to go with stuff we've learned already. Unfortunately, we haven't learned  Map yet.

Comment: I thought that might be the case.  I recommend that after you do your homework, you look into how you would accomplish this with maps.  If you instructor is not going to cover Java's collections this semester, learn it yourself, ASAP.  http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/collections/index.html